# How to make Icons in "Details View" Bigger on Windows 7/8

Tags: windows

I do like the "Details View" of Windows 8 that is actually the same as in Windows 7. I'm referring to the view option of the items in a folder (Being more folders, photos, videos, etc).
The thing is, I need the icons to look bigger, BUT keeping the info on the right of the list (Date modified, type, size, etc).
I tried some tricks with the registry editor, but all unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

Type `metrics` in the Start Menu search box and click on `Change window colors and metrics`. Then try fiddling with the icon size/spacing related settings as shown below and see if it helps:

[image]

Comment: These options only affect icon size in Tiled view and on the desktop.  These do not affect icon size on list view.

Comment: I can't imagine why this got 2 upvotes,  it doesn't answer the question.